# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

When I upgrade from angular 8 to angular 9, I am getting a wired error saying that "Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'." when I run "npm install", below is the code that is getting this error.

```
let A = "";
if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
...
}else{
  B.fromError(error).then(errors => {
        A = errors.splice(0, 5).map(function(re) {
            return res.toString();
          });
  console.log(A);
}
```

Comment: `A` is of type `string` because that's what you initialise it as. Later on you're trying to assign an array of strings to it. That's where the type conflict comes from.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds odd to declare variable `A` as a string (initializing it to an empty string) and later in the `else` statement, you're assigning it a string array.

Answer (score 1):

On the first line you declare `A` as an empty `string`:

```js
let A = "";
```

Then you try to assign `A` the value of `errors`, which is an `Array`

```js
A = errors.splice(0, 5).map(function(re) {
  return res.toString();
});
```

You can't do that.  Maybe replace the first line with:

```js
let A: any[] = [];
```

Or replace `any` with whatever type the elements of `errors` are supposed to be.